# How to check whether the jQuery file is loaded on the page or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check whether jQuery is loaded in the page or not? I have to run a jQuery script which has a jQuery library link, but when I use the code I want to make sure to load that file only if the page does not have any jQuery file, otherwise use that file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
   // This means jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Also, take a look at [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/), it allows you to load different JavaScript files based on if certain conditions are true or false.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
 // jQuery is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest:

```
if( window.jQuery ) { 

 // you code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if jQuery is loaded on the page try:

```
if (!(window.jQuery || window.$)){
 //then load it
} else {
//already loaded
}
```